# Join String with a List of Tuples

Tags: python

Need help with concatenating a String Object with a List of Tuples :

Input :

```
My_String = 'ABC | DEF | GHI'
My_List = [('D1', 2.0), ('D2', 3.0)]
```

Output expected :

```
'ABC | DEF | GHI | D1 | 2.0'
'ABC | DEF | GHI | D2 | 3.0'
```

I tried concatenating, but its doing a cross product with the elements in the tuple and is coming as follows :

```
[
['ABC | DEF | GHI|D1'
'ABC | DEF | GHI | 2.0']
['ABC | DEF | GHI|D2'
'ABC | DEF | GHI | 3.0']
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for name, value in My_List:
    print(' | '.join((My_String, name, str(value))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template and then use `format`:

```
My_String = 'ABC | DEF | GHI'
My_List = [('D1', 2.0), ('D2', 3.0)]

template = My_String + ' | {} | {}'

for i,j in My_List:
    print(template.format(i,j))
```

Output:

```
ABC | DEF | GHI | D1 | 2.0
ABC | DEF | GHI | D2 | 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For the string and tuple you have, the following is a simple and easy to follow way of solving your problem

```
the_string = "ABC | DEF | GHI"
the_list = [('D1', 2.0), ('D2', 3.0)]
#you need to loop through the tuple to get access to the values in the tuple
for i in the_list:
    print the_string, " | "+ str(i[0])+" | "+ str(i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `format`, and tuple unpacking:

```
print map(lambda x: "{} | {} | {}".format(My_String, *x), My_List)
```